# How to optimize min and max to find highest score sum

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, optimization, mathematical-optimization

This problem involves finding two min-max criteria filters to generate the highest score sum in a dataset.

I have a dataset, with 3 columns. x, y, score, with over 1 million of rows.

| x | y | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.6 | 1.2 | -5 |
| 4.2 | 1.2 | -4 |
| 1.2 | 30.2 | 1 |
| 2.9 | 6.8 | 6 |
| 3.1 | 5.8 | 7 |
| 0.1 | 15.8 | 7 |

The data may or may not have a correlation.

I want to find a criteria filter of min/max on x and y that gives me the highest possible sum of scores.

This is how the query would look like in SQL.

```
SELECT SUM(score) 
FROM mytable
WHERE
x > xmin AND x < xmax AND
y > ymin AND y < ymax
```

What I am looking for is the optimal values for xmin, xmax, ymin och ymax

What kind of optimization method is needed to solve this problem? And exactly how would the implementation look like?

(Preferrably it would be implemented using Java or postgres sql.)

Comment: You should probably be looking into a GIST index.

Comment: Since this is an optimization problem possibly via linear programming, consider looking into data science solutions (R, Python, Matlab, SAS, etc.) that imports Postgres table.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I Will look into GIST index.

Comment: @Parfait do you have experience with this kind of optimization problems? What optimization algoritm do you suggest to use?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  I read about GIST-indexes but I do not see how it could be used to find optimal min/max values?

Comment: How are you defining "optimal"?  Obviously, the "optimal" by the definition in the question would be the overall minimum and maximum along each dimension.

Comment: Do you have negative scores? Otherwise just use `x/ymin=-infinity, x/ymax=+infinity`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that scores can be negative. I will update the description

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  Optimal is defined by having the maximum sum of scores as possible. Since scores can be negative there will exist ranges where the sum is more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so easy. Here is my MIP model:

```
minimize sum(i, selected(i)*score(i))
x(i) <= xmin + M*(xBetween(i)+xAbove(i))
x(i) >= xmax - M*(xBetween(i)+xBelow(i))
x(i) >= xmin - M*xBelow(i)
x(i) <= xmax + M*xAbove(i)
y(i) <= ymin + M*(yBetween(i)+yAbove(i))
y(i) >= ymax - M*(yBetween(i)+yBelow(i))
y(i) >= ymin - M*yBelow(i)
y(i) <= ymax + M*yAbove(i)
xBetween(i)+xAbove(i)+xBelow(i)=1
yBetween(i)+yAbove(i)+yBelow(i)=1
selected(i) <= xBetween(i)
selected(i) <= yBetween(i)
selected(i) >= xBetween(i)+yBetween(i)-1
xmin <= xmax
ymin <= ymax
xBetween(i),xAbove(i),xBelow(i) ∈ {0,1}
yBetween(i),yAbove(i),yBelow(i) ∈ {0,1}
selected(i) ∈ {0,1}
```

The constants M are large enough numbers (I used the range of x or y data).

With some random numbers, I got:

```
----     37 VARIABLE z.L                   =       30.940  objective

----     44 PARAMETER data  data + results

                      x           y       score      x.betw      y.betw    selected

i1                1.717       6.611      -8.972
i2                8.433       7.558      -9.880
i3                5.504       6.274      -1.975
i4                3.011       2.839       0.398       1.000       1.000       1.000
i5                2.922       0.864       2.578       1.000       1.000       1.000
i6                2.241       1.025      -5.485                   1.000
i7                3.498       6.413      -2.078       1.000
i8                8.563       5.453      -4.480                   1.000
i9                0.671       0.315      -6.953
i10               5.002       7.924       8.726
i11               9.981       0.728      -1.547                   1.000
i12               5.787       1.757      -7.307                   1.000
i13               9.911       5.256      -2.279                   1.000
i14               7.623       7.502      -2.507
i15               1.307       1.781      -4.630                   1.000
i16               6.397       0.341       8.967
i17               1.595       5.851      -6.221                   1.000
i18               2.501       6.212      -4.050       1.000
i19               6.689       3.894      -8.509                   1.000
i20               4.354       3.587      -1.973                   1.000
i21               3.597       2.430      -7.966                   1.000
i22               3.514       2.464      -2.322                   1.000
i23               1.315       1.305      -3.518                   1.000
i24               1.501       9.334      -6.157
i25               5.891       3.799      -7.753                   1.000
i26               8.309       7.834       1.931
i27               2.308       3.000       0.229       1.000       1.000       1.000
i28               6.657       1.255      -9.099                   1.000
i29               7.759       7.489       5.662
i30               3.037       0.692       8.915       1.000       1.000       1.000
i31               1.105       2.020       1.929                   1.000
i32               5.024       0.051       2.147
i33               1.602       2.696      -2.750                   1.000
i34               8.725       4.999       1.881                   1.000
i35               2.651       1.513       3.597       1.000       1.000       1.000
i36               2.858       1.742       0.132       1.000       1.000       1.000
i37               5.940       3.306      -6.815                   1.000
i38               7.227       3.169       3.138                   1.000
i39               6.282       3.221       0.478                   1.000
i40               4.638       9.640      -7.512
i41               4.133       9.936       9.734
i42               1.177       3.699      -5.438                   1.000
i43               3.142       3.729       3.513       1.000       1.000       1.000
i44               0.466       7.720       5.536
i45               3.386       3.967       8.649       1.000       1.000       1.000
i46               1.821       9.131      -5.975
i47               6.457       1.196      -4.057                   1.000
i48               5.607       7.355      -6.055
i49               7.700       0.554      -5.073
i50               2.978       5.763       2.930       1.000       1.000       1.000
range(data)       9.516       9.885      19.614
min(solution)     2.241       0.554
max(solution)     3.498       5.851
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I am not familiar with MIP modells, but I am trying to understand your code. Would it be possible to explain what you are doing there with pseudo code, or comments above each line?

Comment: There is no code presented here. These are mathematical equations. It's more a proof of concept: we can, with some effort, develop a (linear) Mixed-Integer Programming (MIP) model that solves this problem. But it is a bit too much for a first mathematical optimization model to be exposed to. Not all problems yield easy, small models. You may want to look into meta heuristics, such as genetic algorithms. These are closer to programming code, and they are easier to understand for developers with a computer science background.

Comment: Okey. I understand. I see that you have also presented a result table with input and output. Is this result from the MIP-model? What kind of solver did you use to generate the solution?

Comment: I used GAMS+CPLEX. I did make sure not to use special facilities (such as indicator constraints). So, this model can be solved with any MIP solver.